# User Defined Function Returning #Value

Tags: excel, vba, udf

I have come across a situation which required me to average the result of an array of Vlookups. I had no idea how to achieve this with formulas and it seemed like nobody else on StackOverflow had any idea either.

So I decided to write a function to do the job for me. Unfortunately it returns the "#VALUE!" error and I have no idea why! The function works fine when tested with a msgbox. I have annotated my code below:

```
Option Explicit

Public Function AvgVlookup(Target_Array As String, Lookup_Array As String, Column_Index As Long) As Double

Dim Result As Double
Dim Total As Double
Dim Counter As Long
Dim TargetRange As Range
Dim LookupRange As Range
Dim Cell As Range

' Remove Absolute Indicator
Target_Array = Replace(Target_Array, "$", "")
Lookup_Array = Replace(Lookup_Array, "$", "")

' Convert String to Range
Set TargetRange = Range(Left(Target_Array, InStr(1, Target_Array, ":") - 1), Mid(Target_Array, InStr(1, Target_Array, ":") + 1))
Set LookupRange = Range(Left(Lookup_Array, InStr(1, Lookup_Array, ":") - 1), Mid(Lookup_Array, InStr(1, Lookup_Array, ":") + 1))

' Set Variables to 0
Counter = 0
Total = 0

' For each cell in defined array
For Each Cell In TargetRange

' Vlookup the cell and save lookup value to Result variable
    Result = Application.WorksheetFunction.vlookup(Cell, LookupRange, Column_Index, "False")

' Update variables used to calculate average
    Total = Total + Result
    Counter = Counter + 1

Next Cell

' Perform calculation
AvgVlookup = Total / Counter

End Function
```

---

```
Sub test()

MsgBox AvgVlookup("A5:A8", "G5:H8", 2)

End Sub
```

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: have you placed a break-line in the function and stepped through it line-by-line by to evaluate excactly where the error occurs?

Comment: Hi Scott. There is no error in the code itself. I can run it via the test sub and it will return exactly the result I want into the msgbox. It just returns this error in the cell I enter it into for some reason.

Comment: *There is no error in the code itself* ... and then ... *just returns this error in the cell* ... so there must be something off with the code if its not returning the value to the cell. If you place a break point in the code and then hit `F2` in the cell where it's located you can step-through line-by-line to see why its returning the error message. But I think @ScottCraner has you taken care of :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things:

First, the way you are setting your ranges are a little long, it can be truncated to simply:

```
Set TargetRange = Range(Target_Array)
```

No need to parse the strings after removing the `$`.

Second, you need to put in an error check in case one of the values in the target range is not in the lookup range.

The whole code:

```
Public Function AvgVlookup(Target_Array As String, Lookup_Array As String, Column_Index As Long) As Double


Dim Total As Double
Dim Counter As Long
Dim TargetRange As Range
Dim LookupRange As Range
Dim Cell As Range

' Remove Absolute Indicator
Target_Array = Replace(Target_Array, "$", "")
Lookup_Array = Replace(Lookup_Array, "$", "")

' Convert String to Range
Set TargetRange = Range(Target_Array)
Set LookupRange = Range(Lookup_Array)

' Set Variables to 0
Counter = 0
Total = 0

' For each cell in defined array
For Each Cell In TargetRange

' Vlookup the cell and save lookup value to Result variable
    Dim Result
    Result = Application.VLookup(Cell, LookupRange, Column_Index, "False")
    If IsNumeric(Result) Then
        Total = Total + Result
        Counter = Counter + 1
    End If


Next Cell

' Perform calculation
AvgVlookup = Total / Counter

End Function
```

With the above function to call from the worksheet you would need to call it like this: `=AvgVlookup("A5:A8", "G5:H8", 2)`

But that is not very helpful.  If you change your inputs to ranges:

```
Public Function AvgVlookup(TargetRange As Range, LookupRange As Range, Column_Index As Long) As Double

Dim Result As Double
Dim Total As Double
Dim Counter As Long
Dim Cell As Range


' Set Variables to 0
Counter = 0
Total = 0

' For each cell in defined array
For Each Cell In TargetRange

' Vlookup the cell and save lookup value to Result variable
    Dim t
    t = Application.VLookup(Cell, LookupRange, Column_Index, "False")
    If IsNumeric(t) Then
        Total = Total + t
        Counter = Counter + 1
    End If


Next Cell

' Perform calculation
AvgVlookup = Total / Counter

End Function
```

Then you would call it simply, `=AvgVlookup($A$5:$A$8,$G$5:$H$8,2)`.  This way you can just highlight the correct ranges and it will work.  Also less typing trying to convert a string to a range when what you want to enter is a range.

[image]

Comment: Hi Scott, your amendments work with the test sub I posted. Great to know I can shorten my code but it still produced the #Value! error when used in a worksheet. If this worked for you then I am not sure it why it would produce the error for me.

Comment: With out seeing your data it is hard to tell.  It does work for me. @IIIBarcodeIII

Comment: Sorry you said you are using this in a worksheet? then we need to change a few things. Give me a second. @IIIBarcodeIII

Comment: Thanks Scott, my workday is just about over. I need to take care of a few things before I go so I will test the amendments tomorrow and get back to you. Thanks for your help! It looks like i was on the right track, but over complicating it.